# Geospatial radius query error with in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Good I have a database with records that have a latitude and longitude stored if as a radius in KM (it is the distance from your point which they want to be seen).

I have a use case that should provide a point (latitude and longitude) to return all the records that its radius matches the latitude and longitude of the search.

I have this code, but I can't get it, what it returns is in order the records closest to the search point (it would have to be the other way around). Return the records that your radio is in the latitude and longitude of the search.

```
const documents = await collection.find({
      'location.point': {
        $within: {
          $centerSphere: [
            [longitude, latitude],
            10/6378.1
          ]
        }
      }
    })
```

If anyone can help me with what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it. I'm very lost.

Comment: Can you clarify what issue you are running into? Also, what version are you using? `$within` was deprecated in Mongo 2.4, so if you're using a newer version you should use `$geoWithin`. Current `$geoWithin` documentation shows using the radius of the earth in miles, not km (so divide by `3963.2` instead). If the issue is order, you can sort on `relevance`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the query I put as an example works, it returns me the closest records but my use case is different. I need it to return through a putno (lat, long) to return the records whose radius matches the lat long of the query

Comment: I'm to sure I follow your last sentence. You say you need to return "through a putno (lat, long)", but I'm not sure what that means. It's also unclear what it means to return the records "whose radius matches the lat long of the query". It *sounds* like your records have both a location and radius, and that you only want to provide a lat/lon as the query input. Is that correct? If so, check out $geoNear, which can return the distance. You can then filter on the distance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, if I think you are right. The records that are in the database have a radius field (which represents a radius in miles from the distance of your latitude and longitude). It is the distance in which you want to show. So what is required is that it only returns the records that through a query (With latitude and longitude) coincide in distance with the radius of the database records.

Comment: From what you say with the $ geoNear I could calculate the distance and then whose distance and radius match, return the results?

Comment: I would expect so. Although, I'm curious, does replacing `10/6378.1` with `$divide: [ $location.radius', 6378.1 ]` work for you? It assumes your `location` field is where you have both the `point` and `radius`.